# Directshow filter access threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, com, directshow

I made a TV-Player in c# using directshowlib-2005.
now I made a method to search for available channels.

I want this method to run in a different thread so my GUI won't freeze, but I get an error when I try to set the channel in the method. It can't find the IAMTVTuner interface in my graph, altough I know it's there.

If I don't use a different thread, the method works just fine (but my GUI freezes for a while)

I know it has to do something with apartments, but is there a way I can acces that interface in a different thread then the thread where created my graph in?

Comment: What is the **exact** error? Is it an exception or some sort of "status message" from the app itself?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is because some com classes or interfaces like in the `DirectShowLib` should be just accessed from **the same thread that it was created on**. 
So the solution to this problem is to implement [ISynchronizeInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isynchronizeinvoke.aspx) "System.ComponentModel.ISynchronizeInvoke".

For example if you need to access methods in the class named `Media` that uses internally some classes or methods from the `DirectshowLib` in multithreading mode, you have to check if invoke required by using `InvokeRequired` and if true you have to access it via `Invoke` method.
To demonstrate how to implement `ISynchronizeInvoke` interface here is a snippet from a code that I develop some time ago in C# 2.0

```
public abstract class Media : ISynchronizeInvoke
{
        //....

        private readonly System.Threading.SynchronizationContext _currentContext = System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current;

        private readonly System.Threading.Thread _mainThread = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread;

        private readonly object _invokeLocker = new object();
        //....


        #region ISynchronizeInvoke Members

        public bool InvokeRequired
        {
            get
            {
                return System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId != this._mainThread.ManagedThreadId;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method is not supported!
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="method"></param>
        /// <param name="args"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [Obsolete("This method is not supported!", true)]
        public IAsyncResult BeginInvoke(Delegate method, object[] args)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("The method or operation is not implemented.");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method is not supported!
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="method"></param>
        /// <param name="args"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [Obsolete("This method is not supported!", true)]
        public object EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("The method or operation is not implemented.");
        }

        public object Invoke(Delegate method, object[] args)
        {
            if (method == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("method");
            }

            lock (_invokeLocker)
            {
                object objectToGet = null;

                SendOrPostCallback invoker = new SendOrPostCallback(
                delegate(object data)
                {
                    objectToGet = method.DynamicInvoke(args);
                });

                _currentContext.Send(new SendOrPostCallback(invoker), method.Target);

                return objectToGet;
            }
        }

        public object Invoke(Delegate method)
        {
            return Invoke(method, null);
        }

        #endregion//ISynchronizeInvoke Members

}
```