# WebBrowser control in a class library

Tags: .net, multithreading, webbrowser-control, message-loop

So as the title suggests, I'm trying to use WebBrowser control in a class library. I've gone through several SO questions like [this excellent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269800/webbrowser-control-in-a-new-thread), but the unique thing in my situation is that the WebBrowser object must remain alive for the life of application and keep its state/cookies across different calls that the library clients will make from time to time.

I have confirmed that WebBrowser control does not do navigation unless the thread it was created on contains a message pump. But as soon as I introduce a message pump, the code blocks at `Application.Run()` call and no further events are generated. Any help will really be appricated.

Comment: You'll find a more generic class that supports a browser in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21684059/17034).

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks a ton Hans. I'm giving it a go right now. Appears to be a better candidate.

Comment: For any future reader, the answer link provided by Hans above is exceptionally good. It also has the added advantage that it doesn't depend on .NET 4.5 features such as `async`. Thanks Hans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, you need to run an instance of `WebBrowser` control for the lifetime of your library, and keep it alive and independent on a dedicated STA thread with its own WinForms message loop.

The code below shows how it can possibly be done, using a helper class called `MessageLoopApartment`. Note how the `WebBrowser` gets created and manipulated on a separate thread.

The [Task Parallel Library](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/task-parallel-library/info) is very handy in getting the synchronization job done. The tasks scheduled on the STA thread with `MessageLoopApartment.Run` can be waited synchronously with `task.Wait()` or asynchronously with `await task`, results and exceptions are propagated from the STA thread via `Task.Result`/`Task.Execption`, exceptions are re-thrown on the caller's stack frame.

The implementation of `MessageLoopApartment` **is compatible with NET 4.0**, it doesn't use any .NET 4.5 features. The client code (the `WebBrowser` navigation test) optionally uses [`async/await`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/async-await/info), which may require [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/task-parallel-library/info) to target .NET 4.0. TPL and `async/await` greatly simplify manipulating objects created inside the `MessageLoopApartment`'s thread, like `_webBrowser`.

The navigation test is performed inside `MainForm_Load`, but the lifetime of `_webBrowser` and `_apartment` is not limited by the boundaries of that single call. Both gets destroyed inside `MainForm_FormClosed`. The test app is a WinForms app, but it may as well be a console app or anything else.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinForms_21772632
{
    // https://stackoverflow.com/q/21772632/1768303

    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        MessageLoopApartment _apartment;

        // _webBrowser is created on a separate thread,
        // with MessageLoopApartment.Run
        WebBrowser _webBrowser;

        // MainForm
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // create an independent STA thread
            _apartment = new MessageLoopApartment();

            // create a WebBrowser on that STA thread
            _webBrowser = _apartment.Run(
                () => new WebBrowser(),
                CancellationToken.None).Result;

            this.Load += MainForm_Load;
            this.FormClosed += MainForm_FormClosed;
        }

        // navigation test
        async void MainForm_Load(object senderLoad, EventArgs eLoad)
        {
            // navigate
            var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(10000); // cancel in 10s
            var url = "http://example.com";
            var html = await _apartment.Run(async () =>
            {
                WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler handler = null;
                var navigateTcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
                handler = (s, e) =>
                    navigateTcs.TrySetResult(true);
                _webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += handler;
                try
                {
                    using (cts.Token.Register(() => navigateTcs.TrySetCanceled()))
                    {
                        _webBrowser.Navigate(url);
                        await navigateTcs.Task;
                        return _webBrowser.Document.Body.OuterHtml;
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    _webBrowser.DocumentCompleted -= handler;
                }
            },
            cts.Token);

            // show the HTML of the downloaded page
            MessageBox.Show(html);
        }

        void MainForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            // destroy the WebBrowser
            _apartment.Run(
                () => _webBrowser.Dispose(),
                CancellationToken.None).Wait();

            // shut down the appartment
            _apartment.Dispose();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>MessageLoopApartment</summary>
    public class MessageLoopApartment : IDisposable
    {
        Thread _thread; // the STA thread

        TaskScheduler _taskScheduler; // the STA thread's task scheduler

        public TaskScheduler TaskScheduler { get { return _taskScheduler; } }

        /// <summary>MessageLoopApartment constructor</summary>
        public MessageLoopApartment()
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<TaskScheduler>();

            // start an STA thread and gets a task scheduler
            _thread = new Thread(startArg =>
            {
                EventHandler idleHandler = null;

                idleHandler = (s, e) =>
                {
                    // handle Application.Idle just once
                    Application.Idle -= idleHandler;
                    // return the task scheduler
                    tcs.SetResult(TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
                };

                // handle Application.Idle just once
                // to make sure we're inside the message loop
                // and SynchronizationContext has been correctly installed
                Application.Idle += idleHandler;
                Application.Run();
            });

            _thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            _thread.IsBackground = true;
            _thread.Start();
            _taskScheduler = tcs.Task.Result;
        }

        /// <summary>shutdown the STA thread</summary>
        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (_taskScheduler != null)
            {
                var taskScheduler = _taskScheduler;
                _taskScheduler = null;

                // execute Application.ExitThread() on the STA thread
                Task.Factory.StartNew(
                    () => Application.ExitThread(),
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    TaskCreationOptions.None,
                    taskScheduler).Wait();

                _thread.Join();
                _thread = null;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>A wrapper around Task.Factory.StartNew</summary>
        public Task Run(Action action, CancellationToken token)
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(action, token, TaskCreationOptions.None, _taskScheduler);
        }

        /// <summary>A wrapper around Task.Factory.StartNew to run lambdas with a result</summary>
        public Task<TResult> Run<TResult>(Func<TResult> action, CancellationToken token)
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(action, token, TaskCreationOptions.None, _taskScheduler);
        }

        /// <summary>A wrapper around Task.Factory.StartNew to run async lambdas</summary>
        public Task Run(Func<Task> action, CancellationToken token)
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(action, token, TaskCreationOptions.None, _taskScheduler).Unwrap();
        }

        /// <summary>A wrapper around Task.Factory.StartNew to run async lambdas with a result</summary>
        public Task<TResult> Run<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> action, CancellationToken token)
        {
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(action, token, TaskCreationOptions.None, _taskScheduler).Unwrap();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Noseratio,  Is there a mistake in your 'finally' clause? Maybe could be: `_webBrowser.DocumentCompleted -= handler;` I would really appreciate if you can share the reason, in case the code line is correct

Comment: @Ayorus, indeed there's a bug, it should be `_webBrowser.DocumentCompleted -= handler`.

Comment: Hi @Noseratio, I have been using this piece of code for the last 2 weeks. However, After implemented the following error has appeared: `Appcrash mshtml.dll Fault Module Version: 11.0.9600.18500 Exception Code: c00000fd` I looked for some references about it and it turns out it is related to iExplorer. Have you ever face it? Do you have any recomendation?

Comment: @Ayorus, no I haven't seen this but then I haven't ever stress-tested this code. Looks to me like an IE bug, a memory leak perhaps. You may try using multiple `MessageLoopApartment` instances and recycling them. That should be properly killing `WebBrowser` instances.