# How can I login to a website using WatiN asynchronously?

Tags: c#, wpf, task-parallel-library, watin

I'm using [`WatiN`](http://watin.org/) to login a website. `WatiN` requires [`STAThread` attribute](http://watin.org/documentation/sta-apartmentstate/) to be applied on the thread that will be running on. Until now all things were good but now I have a long-task. I'm using `WPF` and need to keep `UI` responsive. So I have tried something like this:

```
_downloadTask = new Task(StartDownload, _cancelationToken.Token);

[STAThread]
public override void StartDownload()
{
    if(IsLoginNeeded)
    {
       bool result = Login();
       // check the result and do some other work..
    }
}

[STAThread]
public bool Login()
{
     if (_browser == null)
           _browser = new IE(LoginUrl); // exception

}
```

When I started my Task, I get `ThreadStateException` on `new IE(LoginUrl)` :

> The `CurrentThread` needs to have it's `ApartmentState` set to `ApartmentState.STA` to be able to automate Internet Explorer.

As you  can see I have tried to apply  `STAThread` on my methods but I couldn't succeeded.Now I'm wondering if it's possible to apply `STAThread` attribute to a thread that is created on runtime or is there another way to do this?

Comment: @Servy has a nice Task wrapper around the `Thread` class [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720496/set-apartmentstate-on-a-task)

Comment: You can also use my [`MessageLoopApartment`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21808747/1768303), it provides familiar `Task Run(Action)` and `Task<T> Run(Func<Task<T>>)` wrappers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Thread t = new Thread(() =>
{
    StartDownload();
    Application.Run();
});
t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
t.Start();
```