# Catch global hook events (mouse keyboard) from an other thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, hook, global

Hi made a hook library that catches global events from the keyboard and mouse.

```
   `private bool Install()     //this function install all the hooks (mouse/keyobard) 
    {                            
        bool started=true;
        started &= _globalMouse.Install();
        started &= _globalKeyboard.Install();

        if(!started)
        {
            Uninstall();
        }
        return started;
    }

    private void Uninstall() //this function unistall all the hooks
    {
        _globalMouse.Uninstall();
        _globalKeyboard.Uninstall();
    }


    private void run()   // this is the method that is called by the thread to register and 
                         // there should be caught all the global events (mouse/keyboard) 
    {

        Instance.Install();
       while(_running)
       {
           Thread.Sleep(0);
       }

        Instance.Uninstall();
    }`
```

this is the creation and starting thread function:

```
        public bool Start()
        {
            if(_thread!=null && _thread.IsAlive)
            {
                return true;
            }
            _running = true;
            _thread = new Thread(run);
            _thread.Start();
            return _running;
        }
```

The problem is that if I use the method `Install()`directly from my form it's working. If it was the method `start()` that should start the thread it isn't working (yes the thread remains alive, and yes I caught the needed event in the form correctly (worked with `Install()` function).

I read on different pages that I need a cycle to pump messages from/to the system, but I don't know how to make it.

My question is how I can make my thread able to catch global events that worked fine in my form thread.

Comment: You have to pump a message loop, Application.Run().  Altogether a better alternative than a while() loop that burns 100% core :)

Comment: it's normaly that my cursor keeps flickering ? and then how to stop the thread? i tried that before and i though that was merging the threads

Comment: Application.ExitThread() stops it.  No idea what a flickering cursor could mean, you give no context at all.  If you already have a form then there's no point in doing this at all.

Comment: if i call Application.ExitThread(); from my form, the form stops but my thread is still going, how to call that function from the second thread context?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21684059/17034

Comment: thanks a lot, i lost a day for those things

Comment: Hmm, threading ought to cost you at least a month of your life.  You haven't actually got it working yet, those events fire on the wrong thread :)

Comment: What do you mean? That was working for me. Will it make me latter problems?