# Can't Get WindowsApiCodePack ShellFile Thumbnail Async

Tags: c#, windows-api-code-pack

I am trying to get the thumbnails for files in a directory asynchronously. All files except PDFs seem to work async.

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
{
    var task = await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    { 
         using(ShellFile shellFile = ShellFile.FromFilePath(filePath))
         {
             ImageSource source = shellFile.Thumbnail.MediumBitmapSource;
             source.Freeze();
             return source;
         }
    });
    image.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => image.Source = task.Result);
}
```

All other files return correctly. However, if I call all of this code a second time if image.source == null then it works fine.

**edit**
My working code after Hans Passant's answer

```
var thread = new Thread(() =>
{
    using(ShellFile shellFile = ShellFile.FromFilePath(filePath))
    {
         ImageSource source = shellFile.Thumbnail.MediumBitmapSource;
         source.Freeze();
    }
    image.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => image.Source = source);
});

thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();
```

Thanks!

Comment: The task runs on a thread that is very unfriendly to the kind of files that use a shell extension to generate their thumbnail.  Like pdfs.  They need an STA thread.  You can find one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21684059/17034).

Comment: @HansPassant if you put this in an answer I'll accept it. Regardless, thanks for the help. I'll edit my question to show my working code.

Comment: A hard requirement for an STA thread is that it must pump a message loop.  You might get away with not doing this, you know you didn't if a user of your program reports a deadlock.