# C# Marshalling to call C++ DLL. COM and threading issue

Tags: c#, c++, dll, com, marshalling

When I try to call a extern method from a non-main thread, I get COM CoInitialize error from the DLL written in C++ thread.

Just for slight more details, I have define an alias to call the c++ method in my C# console project.

e.g. 
[DllImport("WRITTENINC++.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern Int32 DOTHIS(string s1, string s2, ref double d1, ref double d2);

And I put [STAThread] on top of Program.Main method.

When I call the method in the main thread, I get the correct result. However, if I run the same lines of codes in a different thread (using System.Threading and thread.Start()), I get the error regarding COM initialization.

Assuming that I cannot modify the DLL, the only way right now is to restrict my program to single-thread, which is not exciting.

Is there any solution to this?

Thanks!

Comment: Add the exact error. Either your thread hasn't been initialized for COM or it's in the wrong apartment state.

Comment: It looks like that DLL uses some STA COM objects stored in global variables, a bad design which would force you calling `DOTHIS` on the same thread the DLL was initialized.

Comment: It is a pretty gross bug for code in a DLL to call CoInitializeEx().  Especially asking for STA, a DLL can never make that promise.  Do strongly consider not using this DLL, it probably isn't the only bug.  Use code [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21684059/17034) if you have to.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call CoInitialize() on every thread where you use COM.