# COM execution as backgroung in WPF without hanging UI

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0

I am calling COM dll in WPF and want that UI doesn't Hang.
So far i have used  Task.Run  approaches but no result.

Here is the code

```
   public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Task.Run(() => DoWork());

        }


 private  void DoWork()
    {

         Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Allocate();

        });

    }



 void Allocate()
        {

            int idwErrorCode = 0;


            try
            {  
                bIsConnected = axCZKEM1.Connect_Net("192.168,2,2", 3703);


            }
```

the COM method  **axCZKEM1.Connect_Net("192.168,2,2", 3703)** execution takes time and UI hangs up.

Need a simple solution.

Comment: Did you try to use threads ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173178.aspx That would explicitely use another thread to run your COM method

Comment: And.... you're running a Task..... Inside another Task ?

Comment: Threading is not a minor detail, the COM runtime knows whether or not the object is thread-safe and which thread owns the object.  So when you call a method on a worker thread then COM takes care of automatically marshaling the call to the thread that owns the object.  Very similar to the way Dispatcher.Invoke() works but completely automatic.  So your UI thread still hangs.  Workaround is to *create* the object on a worker thread so that this thread owns it and executes its methods.  It must be STA and pump a message loop, [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21684059/17034).

Comment: Fwiw, the "ax" prefix spells doom, suggests that it is actually an ActiveX control with a user interface and that you used the AxHost wrapper and ElementHost to put on a WPF window.  Can't run that one on another thread.  Do this early, use a splash screen to hide the delay.