# Updating a UI component using Invoke Async Deadlock

Tags: c#, user-interface, begininvoke, sta

I am using devexpress and their PivotGrid control to build a pivot grid. I don't care about displaying it I have no actual UI displayed, I want the PivotGrid so I can export it.

Therefore I am creating and updating the pivot grid object on a separate STA thread else it won't work. I execute the method that handles the retrieving of data through the following code:

```
 PivotGridControl pivotGrid = null;
 Thread thread = new Thread(() => { pivotGrid = _reportProcessor.RunReport(currentReport.ReportId).Result; });
 thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
 thread.Start();
 thread.Join();
```

The part of the RunReport method that isn't working is the following:

```
 public async Task<PivotGridControl> RunReport(int reportId)
    {
        //var pivotGrid = new PivotGridFactory().GetPivotGrid();

        var pivotGrid = new PivotGridControl();

        //Get report info
        var report = await _reportReferenceService.GetReportReference(reportId);

        //Get data definition
        var dataDefinition = await _reportDataDefService.GetDataDefinition(report.DataDefinitionId);

        //Get fields
        var fields = await _reportFieldService.GetFields(FieldSetId);

        //Get layout
        var layout = await _reportLayoutService.GetLayout(report.LayoutId);
        var layoutStream = StreamUtils.StringToStream(layout.Definition);
        var collapseStream = StreamUtils.Base64StringToStream(layout.CollapseState);
        await pivotGrid.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(delegate
        {
            pivotGrid.BeginUpdate();
            pivotGrid.Fields.Clear();
            pivotGrid.Fields.Where(x => x.Visible).ForEach(x => x.Visible = false);
            pivotGrid.RestoreLayoutFromStream(layoutStream);
            pivotGrid.RestoreCollapsedStateFromStream(collapseStream);
            pivotGrid.AllowConditionalFormattingMenu = true;
            pivotGrid.AllowConditionalFormattingManager = true;
            pivotGrid.EndUpdate();
        });

        //Get field spec
        var fieldSpec = _reportFieldService.GetFieldSpecification(pivotGrid.Fields);

        //Get report data 
        var reportData = await _reportDataService.GetReportData(fieldSpec, dataDefinition.FundDataSpecification, dataDefinition.DifferenceSpecification, dataDefinition.TimeSeriesSpecification, dataDefinition.RiskDataSpecification, null);

        //Set pivot data
        pivotGrid.BeginUpdate();
        pivotGrid.DataSource = reportData;
        pivotGrid.EndUpdate();

        return pivotGrid;

    }
```

As it is this locks and the delegate is never run, I'm assuming there is a deadlock somewhere but I'm surprised the delegate isn't run at all.

Comment: `.Result;` is what causes the deadlock

Comment: Thanks @Nkosi if I remove the .Result the delegate doesn't run at all

Comment: Because you are suppose to call `PivotGridControl pivotGrid = await _reportProcessor.RunReport(currentReport.ReportId)`

Comment: do not mix async calls with blocking calls like `.Result` or `.Wait()`

Comment: Marking a thread STA is a promise, cross your heart, hope to die.  You didn't keep the promise, so you died.  An STA thread needs to have a dispatcher and its Run() method must have been called.  No Run call so no dispatching, Invoke will always deadlock.  Getting a usable solution is difficult, it is unclear why Invoke is necessary at all given that it should be the worker thread that owns the control.  An example [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21684059/17034), wrong flavor.

Comment: Hmm @HansPassant I think you're right, I am surprised I need the dispatcher anyway, it should just work but it gives me the STA error, maybe because it's an async method?

Comment: @Nkosi I changed it to 

Thread thread = new Thread(async () => { PivotGridControl pivotGrid = await _reportProcessor.RunReport(currentReport.ReportId); });

Now I get the task was cancelled error

Comment: Sorry when I do it without the dispatch it's saying another thread owns the object