# BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress doesn't display changes in my UI

Tags: wpf, vb.net, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have a compare button which starts a background worker.

```
Private Sub btnCompare_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCompare.Click

    m_ProgressBar = New ProgressBar
    m_ProgressBar.Show()
    m_ProgressBar.txtBlockMainProgress.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub()
                                                                  m_ProgressBar.txtBlockMainProgress.Text = "Comparing excel file(s)... Please wait. This might take a while."
                                                              End Sub)

    Me.backgroundWorker = New BackgroundWorker
    Me.backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    Me.backgroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
    AddHandler Me.backgroundWorker.DoWork, AddressOf worker_DoWork
    AddHandler Me.backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged, AddressOf worker_ProgressChanged
    AddHandler Me.backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf worker_RunWorkerCompleted
    Me.backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
    TaskbarItemInfo.ProgressState = Shell.TaskbarItemProgressState.Normal

End Sub
```

The DoWork Event of my backgroundworker initialize a class Compare that has a method named Compare which accept a backgroundworker as parameter

```
    Private Sub worker_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)

    blnCompareDone = True

    objExcelCompare = New Compare

    With objExcelCompare
        .SetThreshold = dblThreshold
        .CompareToBestMatchData = blnBestMatchFlg

        .CompareMerge = blnCompareMerge
        .CompareTextWrap = blnCompareTextWrap
        .CompareTextAlign = blnCompareTextAlign
        .CompareOrientation = blnCompareOrientation
        .CompareBorder = blnCompareBorder
        .CompareBackColor = blnCompareBackColor
        .CompareFont = blnCompareFont

        .NoOfPages = intNoOfPages
        .Page_Location_1 = objLocation_1
        .Page_Location_2 = objLocation_2
        .RemovedColumn = objRemoveCol
        .RemovedRow = objRemoveRow
        .AddedColumn = objAddCol
        .AddedRow = objAddRow
        .DataChange = objChangeData

        .Compare(objWorksheet_1, objWorksheet_2, Me.backgroundWorker, e)

        objEquivalentColumns = .EquivalentColumns
        objEquivalentRows = .EquivalentRows
        objValueResult_1 = .ValueResult_1
        objValueResult_2 = .ValueResult_2
        objFormatResult = .FormatResult
    End With

End Sub
```

Inside the compare method i use ReportProgress to update my UI after comparing each page of excel file. There are total of 2 pages so the updating of progress bar will be 50% then 100%.

```
    Public Sub Compare(ByRef p_objWorkSheet_1 As Worksheet, ByRef p_objWorkSheet_2 As Worksheet, ByRef p_backgroundWorker As BackgroundWorker, ByRef e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)

    If p_objWorkSheet_1 Is Nothing OrElse p_objWorkSheet_2 Is Nothing Then
        'Error when no instance on either worksheets was found
        Throw New Exception("No instances of worksheet is found.")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    '********************Start of Comparison*********************
    objExcelData_1 = New Dictionary(Of Integer, Dictionary(Of Tuple(Of Integer, Integer), Range))
    objExcelData_2 = New Dictionary(Of Integer, Dictionary(Of Tuple(Of Integer, Integer), Range))

    objEquivalentColumns = New Dictionary(Of Integer, Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer))
    objEquivalentRows = New Dictionary(Of Integer, Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer))

    objValueResult_1 = New Dictionary(Of Integer, Dictionary(Of Tuple(Of Integer, Integer), List(Of ValueError)))
    objValueResult_2 = New Dictionary(Of Integer, Dictionary(Of Tuple(Of Integer, Integer), List(Of ValueError)))
    objFormatResult = New Dictionary(Of Integer, Dictionary(Of Tuple(Of Integer, Integer), List(Of FormatError)))

    'Loop through all pages
    For w_intCtr_1 As Integer = 1 To intNoOfPages

        If p_backgroundWorker.CancellationPending = True Then
            e.Cancel = True
            Return
        End If

        Dim w_intCurrentStep As Integer = 1
        GetExcelData(p_objWorkSheet_1, objExcelData_1, objLocation_1, w_intCtr_1)
        GetExcelData(p_objWorkSheet_2, objExcelData_2, objLocation_2, w_intCtr_1)

        If objExcelData_1 Is Nothing OrElse objExcelData_2 Is Nothing Then
            'No data to compare
            Exit Sub
        End If

        objCompareByData = New Compare_Data

        'Compare value of excelsheets
        With objCompareByData
            'Set threshold, excel data, and location of page to compare
            .SetThreshold = dblThreshold
            .CompareToBestMatchData = blnBestMatchFlg

            .SetExcelData_1 = objExcelData_1(w_intCtr_1)
            .SetLocation_1 = objLocation_1(w_intCtr_1)

            .SetExcelData_2 = objExcelData_2(w_intCtr_1)
            .SetLocation_2 = objLocation_2(w_intCtr_1)

            If objRemoveCol Is Nothing = False AndAlso objRemoveCol.ContainsKey(w_intCtr_1) Then
                .SetRemovedColumn = objRemoveCol(w_intCtr_1)
            End If
            If objRemoveRow Is Nothing = False AndAlso objRemoveRow.ContainsKey(w_intCtr_1) Then
                .SetRemovedRow = objRemoveRow(w_intCtr_1)
            End If
            If objAddCol Is Nothing = False AndAlso objAddCol.ContainsKey(w_intCtr_1) Then
                .SetAddedColumn = objAddCol(w_intCtr_1)
            End If
            If objAddRow Is Nothing = False AndAlso objAddRow.ContainsKey(w_intCtr_1) Then
                .SetAddedRow = objAddRow(w_intCtr_1)
            End If

            If objChangeData Is Nothing = False AndAlso objChangeData.ContainsKey(w_intCtr_1) Then
                .SetDataChange = objChangeData(w_intCtr_1)
            End If

            If p_backgroundWorker.CancellationPending = True Then
                e.Cancel = True
                Return
            End If

            'Proceed to compare
            .Compare()

            objEquivalentColumns.Add(w_intCtr_1, .EquivalentColumns)
            objEquivalentRows.Add(w_intCtr_1, .EquivalentRows)

            objValueResult_1.Add(w_intCtr_1, .ExcelData_Result_1)
            objValueResult_2.Add(w_intCtr_1, .ExcelData_Result_2)
        End With

        If blnCompareMerge OrElse blnCompareTextWrap OrElse blnCompareTextAlign OrElse blnCompareOrientation OrElse blnCompareBorder OrElse blnCompareBackColor OrElse blnCompareFont Then
            objCompareByFormat = New Compare_Format

            'Compare format of excelsheets
            With objCompareByFormat
                'Set excel data to compare
                .SetExcelFormat_1 = objExcelData_1(w_intCtr_1)
                .SetExcelFormat_2 = objExcelData_2(w_intCtr_1)
                'Set equivalent columns of page retrieved from comparing values of both excel sheets
                'Set equivalent rows of page retrieved from comparing values of both excel sheets
                If objEquivalentColumns Is Nothing = False AndAlso objEquivalentColumns.ContainsKey(w_intCtr_1) Then
                    .SetEquivalentColumns = objEquivalentColumns(w_intCtr_1)
                End If
                If objEquivalentRows Is Nothing = False AndAlso objEquivalentRows.ContainsKey(w_intCtr_1) Then
                    .SetEquivalentRows = objEquivalentRows(w_intCtr_1)
                End If

                .CompareMerge = blnCompareMerge
                .CompareTextWrap = blnCompareTextWrap
                .CompareTextAlign = blnCompareTextAlign
                .CompareOrientation = blnCompareOrientation
                .CompareBorder = blnCompareBorder
                .CompareBackColor = blnCompareBackColor
                .CompareFont = blnCompareFont

                If p_backgroundWorker.CancellationPending = True Then
                    e.Cancel = True
                    Return
                End If

                .Compare()

                'Set comparison result of page to collection
                objFormatResult.Add(w_intCtr_1, .ExcelFormat_Result)
            End With
        End If

        If p_backgroundWorker.CancellationPending = True Then
            e.Cancel = True
            Return
        End If

        'Set result to excel sheets
        AddValueResultToWorkSheet(p_objWorkSheet_1, p_objWorkSheet_2, w_intCtr_1)

        If p_backgroundWorker.CancellationPending = True Then
            e.Cancel = True
            Return
        End If

        'Set result to excel sheets
        AddFormatResultToWorkSheet(p_objWorkSheet_2, w_intCtr_1)

        p_backgroundWorker.ReportProgress((100 / intNoOfPages) * w_intCtr_1, (100 / intNoOfPages) * w_intCtr_1 & "% Completed " & w_intCtr_1 & " out of " & intNoOfPages & " pages")
        Thread.Sleep(3000)
    Next
End Sub
```

It works fine if i put Thread.Sleep(3000) after every ReportProgress. This is my ProgressChanged event handler

```
Private Sub worker_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs)

    m_ProgressBar.pbStatusMain.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub()
                                                          m_ProgressBar.pbStatusMain.IsIndeterminate = False
                                                          m_ProgressBar.pbStatusMain.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
                                                      End Sub)

    m_ProgressBar.txtBlockMainProgress.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub()
                                                                  m_ProgressBar.txtBlockMainProgress.Text = e.UserState
                                                              End Sub)

    TaskbarItemInfo.ProgressValue = e.ProgressPercentage / 100

End Sub
```

I wonder why sometimes it work and sometimes it doesnt. Based on my research the UI thread is being flooded with message causing it to be unresponsive or I used ReportProgress to frequent which causing the UI thread to ignore the next request. What am i doing wrong? Why the changes doesnt apply in my UI?

Comment: Why are you making those `BeginInvoke` calls in the `ProgressChanged` event handler?  The whole point is that `ProgressChanged` is raised on the UI thread so it is safe to modify the UI directly.  Get rid of those and see whether the situation rights itself.  If not, try calling `Refresh` on the control(s) you modify.

Comment: I tried BeginInvoke, Invoke, Dispatcher but all produce the same result. How do I do that refresh?

Comment: Actually, I was thinking WinForms when I wrote that.  I'm not sure what the equivalent would be in WPF, or if there is one.  Never tried.  To be clear, if you get rid of those `BeginInvoke calls and just keep the contents of the lambdas, the issue remains, right?  I would assume that that's what you started out with.

Comment: Yes. I also tried application.do events still not updating the UI. I already spent weeks in this. Sometimes thread.sleep() is not working.

Comment: Sure, running too much code on the UI thread causes this problem.  It is not just the ReportProgress() and BeginInvoke() calls that are responsible, it is also using the Excel object model in a worker thread.  Which is a COM object model, any methods and properties you use actually execute on the UI thread.  The COM plumbing uses the equivalent of Dispatcher.Invoke() to keep the code thread-safe.  Only real way to get ahead is to create the Application interface on an STA thread so no marshaling is necessary.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/21684059/17034