# Background validation of state, reset on user action

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm really new to threading multitasking/multithreading, but I'm working on a project where I think I need it. The user will be editing a fairly complex diagram, and I want the program to check for validity of the diagram. The validity check is non-trivial (polynomial time, though, not NP - seconds, not minutes or years, but I don't want to hold the user up for a few seconds after every change) so I would like the program to check for validity in the background and highlight inconsistencies when it finds them. When the user makes certain changes to the diagram (changes the structure, not just the labels on elements), the validation will have to throw away what it was doing and start again. I'm assuming the user will eventually take a break to think/go for a pee/go for a coffee/chat to that rather cute person two cubicles along, but in case they don't, I *have* to let the validation run to completion in some circumstances (before a save or a printout, for example). Broad-brush, what are the features of C# I'll need to learn, and how do I structure that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broad Brush. Here we go.

Q: "What are the features of C# I'll need to learn?"

A: You can get by nicely with a basic toolkit consisting (roughly speaking) of:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task
System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource
System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim
```

Q: "I don't want to hold the user up for a few seconds after every change"

A: OK, so we will never-ever block the UI thread. Fire off a Task to run a background validation routine that checks every now and then to see if it's been cancelled.

```
CancellationTokenSource _cts = null;
SemaphoreSlim ssBusy = new SemaphoreSlim(2);
private void ExecValidityCheck()
{
    ssBusy.Wait();
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            LongRunningValidation(_cts.Token);
        }
        finally
        {
            ssBusy.Release();
        }
    })
    .GetAwaiter()
    .OnCompleted(CheckForRestart);
}
```

We'll call **CheckForRestart** using GetAwaiter().OnCompleted(). This just means that *without blocking* we'll be notified as a callback when the thread finishes for one of three reasons:

1. Cancelled
2. Cancelled, but with an intent to start the validation over from the beginning.
3. Ran validation to completion

By calling **CheckForRestart** we determine whether to start it over again or not.

```
void CheckForRestart()
{
    BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        if (_restart)
        {
            _restart = false;
            ExecValidityCheck();
        }
        else
        {
            buttonCancel.Enabled = false;
        }
    });
}
```

Rather that post the complete code here, I pushed a simple [working example](https://github.com/IVSoftware/restartable-validation.git) to our GitHub. You can browse it there or clone and run it. [20-second screen capture](http://ivsoftware.com/stack-overflow/restartable-validation.mp4). When the RESTART button is clicked in the video, it's checking the **CurrentCount** property of the Semaphore. In a threadsafe way it determines whether the validation routine is already running or not.

I hope I've managed to give you a few ideas about where to start. Sure, the explanation I've given here has a few holes but feel free to address your critical concerns in the comments and I'll try to respond.

Comment: @digitig thx! I didn't want to pile too much into the answer, but...you're probably going to need two watchdog (countdown) timers.

Comment: __1.__ You mention that if user activity is such that validation _never_ gets to run all the way through then eventually you'll be _forced_ to spin a wait cursor and allow validation to complete every so often. A WDT set at 5 M (or whatever) countdown _starts_ at the first sign of activity and only resets if validation finishes.

Comment: __2.__ If the user is frantically typing or clicking and _not_ peeing (or perhaps doing both at the same time) why bother starting the validation when you know it will just have to restart in 50 ms? So wait for a second or two before even making an attempt to run the background task. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to learn about [asynchronous programming with async/await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/), and about [cooperative cancellation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads). The standard practice for communicating cancellation is by throwing an `OperationCanceledException`. Methods that are intended to be cancelable accept a [`CancellationToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken) as argument, and observe frequently the `IsCancellationRequested` method of the token. So here is the basic structure of a cancelable `Validate` method with a boolean result:

```
bool Validate(CancellationToken token)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        // Throw an OperationCanceledException if cancellation is requested
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        Thread.Sleep(100); // Simulate some CPU-bound work
    }
    return true;
}
```

The "driver" of the `CancellationToken` is a class named [`CancellationTokenSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource). In your case you'll have to create multiple instances of this class, one for every time that the diagram is changed. You must store them somewhere so that you can call later their `Cancel` method, so lets make two private fields inside the `Form`, one for the most recent `CancellationTokenSource`, and one for the most recent validation [`Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1):

```
private Task<bool> _validateTask;
private CancellationTokenSource _validateCTS;
```

Finally you'll have to write the logic for the event handler of the `Diagram_Changed` event. It is probably not desirable to have multiple validation tasks running side by side, so it's a good idea to `await` for the completion of the previous task before launching a new one. It is important that awaiting a task doesn't block the UI. This introduces the complexity that multiple `Diagram_Changed` events, along with other unrelated events, can occur before the completion of the code inside the handler. Fortunately you can count on the single-threaded nature of the UI, and not have to worry about the thread-safety of accessing the `_validateTask` and `_validateCTS` fields by multiple asynchronous workflows. You do need to be aware though that after every `await` these fields may hold different values than before the `await`.

```
private async void Diagram_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool validationResult;
    using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
    {
        _validateCTS?.Cancel(); // Cancel the existing CancellationTokenSource
        _validateCTS = cts; // Publish the new CancellationTokenSource
        if (_validateTask != null)
        {
            // Await the completion of the previous task before spawning a new one
            try { await _validateTask; }
            catch { } // Ignore any exception
        }
        if (cts != _validateCTS) return; // Preempted (the event was fired again)

        // Run the Validate method in a background thread
        var task = Task.Run(() => Validate(cts.Token), cts.Token);
        _validateTask = task; // Publish the new task

        try
        {
            validationResult = await task; // Await the completion of the task
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            return; // Preempted (the validation was canceled)
        }
        finally
        {
            // Cleanup before disposing the CancellationTokenSource
            if (_validateTask == task) _validateTask = null;
            if (_validateCTS == cts) _validateCTS = null;
        }
    }
    // Do something here with the result of the validation
}
```

The `Validate` method should not include any UI manipulation code, because it will be running in a background thread. Any effects to the UI should occur after the completion of the method, through the returned result of the validation task.