# How to make Visual studio break in on uncaught exception in thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio, debugging, exception

In this sample code, when I call `a()`, the debugger breaks in properly, and I can inspect all local variables and stack frames.
[image]
Now if I call `b()`, I get a completely useless "exception was thrown at ..." where the stack is unraveled already:
[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Which VS version, .NET version etc. are you using?

Comment: .NET 6.0 fixes this behavior.  For 5.0, you could use Tools > Options > Debugging > General, tick "Enable Just My Code".  Which makes no sense whatsoever, but bugs don't need to make sense :)

Comment: I've only contradicted one of @HansPassant (rep 897,294+) comments [one other time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52609592/how-to-pass-booleon-back-from-worker-progresschanged-to-worker-dowork/52611382#52611382). In `Exception Settings` you can check/uncheck the `Break When Thrown` for `[x] System.Exception`. In every version of VS I've used (since V 7 in 2003) this setting determines whether it will or won't break on that line. For the first time ever, the ability to enable or disable it appears to be broken. It _does_ make perfect sense and it's _not_ a bug (Until now. In my opinion :)

Comment: For anyone who sees this question @HansPassant solution worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I reproduced your issue. Try going to Exception Settings and click one time on the box for `Common Language Runtime Exceptions` changing from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

On my test setup when I turn on *all* CLR exceptions to **Break When Thrown** I get the correct breakpoint. If you achieve the same result, the issue is that some exceptions have this disabled by default. They still throw, they just don't *break*. As an alternative to enabling all of them, you can expand the entry to see exactly which ones are disabled and customize the settings if you choose.

[image]

**EDIT** I also ran and confirmed what Hans just stated in his comment, that this always breaks with a .NET 6 Core console app. So the *new* issue seems to be that you can *uncheck* the **break when this exception type is thrown** in the popup, but that setting gets ignored and it breaks anyway.

[image]

Comment: It works, but not exactly the "true" fix. All this does is make **every** exception get broken in on when it is thrown. What I want is to break in on only exceptions that are unhandled. Hans' comment worked for me.

Comment: I'm glad you're moving forward with Han's answer that's the point for sure. Yes, what I _showed_ was turning on `Break When Thrown` for every exception there is. Mainly, I wanted to draw attention to Exceptions Settings - that expanding it offers precise control over what does/doesn't break. E.g. debugging a Unit Test method that is testing cancellations, I have to turn off `System.Operation.Cancelled` or it stops running.

Comment: The thing Hans pointed out about .NET Core 6 leaves me with a new concern; Has there really been a fundamental change in the way this has always behaved? I don't really _want_ to write my Unit Tests all over again :(