# "Not responding" during the execution of function from COM object

Tags: c++, vb.net, openmp, solidworks, comobject

It's been several days that I'm on this problem without finding a solution...

I developed a macro for SolidWorks in VB.NET. It uses a COM object from a DLL that I developed in C++. The functions of this COM object take a long time to run (sometimes more than 30 seconds), and also make use of parallelized loops using OpenMP.

My problem is that when I run one of these functions, after ~10s, the program stops responding, and it freezes my UI! The DLL function is running and we can not send an update to the UI with a `DoEvents()`...

I tried to put the function in a background worker but with COM objects it does not work. The other thing I tried is to make a background worker that accesses my process on a regular time interval to see if it responds. But when it stops responding, I can't force it to answer. The only solution that I found is to change the value of the registry key `HungAppTimeout`, but this applies to everything on my machine whereas I want it applied to just my code.

Would you have a solution to avoid the "no answer"?

Example of code:

```
Public Sub StartfunctionCOM()

   Dim Myclass as COMClass = new COMClass
   Myclass.functiontakemanytime() 'time >10sec

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you may need an STA thread in order for it to do COM correctly.  One way to do this would be to use the task-based parallelism features with a custom tasks scheduler which schedules onto an STA thread.  There is a "parallel extensions extras" package out there somewhere which provides an STA task scheduler.  You would queue your work using `Task.Factory.StartNew` and then `Await` the task which would keep your UI responsive.  If this works for you, I can write it up as an answer.

Comment: @Craig may be on to something. When you say "putting the function in a background worker does not work" what do you mean? What exception do you get?

Comment: I didn't try multithreading in macro only in addins. I suppose it is close. Did you try placing your calling code in separate thread? Or you can modify functiontakemanytime() in the way it creates thread and then starts real functiontakemanytime()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21684059/17034

Comment: @Keith Stein. "putting the function in a background worker does not work", that mean when i launch this background worker, it happen nothing and it wait the doevent. And when doevent is call, backgroundworker function is execute but  on the main thread...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution: I call the function `DisableProcessWindowsGhosting` in my c++ code. It does not prevent the application from "not responding", but it will remove the automatic Windows response (ie the standard "Application does not respond anymore, wait or kill?" message box).