# Form.Show() doesn't allow keyboard input

Tags: c#, .net, forms, winforms, user-interface

So I have made a GUI which I compiled as EXE. The GUI has several textboxes and UpDown controls.
I am starting the GUI from different class and all works fine - I can change/update the controls, I receive proper events and so on. There is 1 very strange problem - the GUI does not accept andy Keyboard input.... nowhere - not in the upDown controls, not in the text boxes... nowhere.
If I start the EXE separately from prompt, it DOES accept keyboard input, but when I start it from my other class/programm it does not.

in my other class what I do is this :

```
myGui form;
...
form    = new myGui();

form.Show();
```

Form is shown normally, I can interact with it and all is good, except I cannot enter anything with the keyboard.
All controls are unlocked. (anyways when the GUI is started directly from prompt it works normally and accepts keyboard)

What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you put a link to a zip containing the project files, please?

Comment: When you run the EXE separately, the Form is displayed as a result of being passed to `Application.Run()`.  What kind of application is your "different class"?

Comment: The other program is called Multicharts.NET  Almost sure you never heard of it  - basically I can create my own C# programs and run them there. That's where I start the gui from using form.Show(); Btw. If I use Application.Run(form) I have the keyboard inputs, but I lose access to all the controls ! Like they become invisible for Multicharts.

Comment: [How to post messages to an STA thread running a message pump?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21684059/7444103)

Comment: Check if the main thread is not locked performing some task on background. If it's happen it's normal you can perform any other task.