Single threaded COM component in ASP .NET Web API
I have a legacy COM dll which exposes business logic via COM objects. Its implemented using VC++. It doesn't support multiple instances in a process.
I am in process of modernising my application for web. Initially I wanted reuse this COM component without any change.How to consume this COM component from my ASP.NET web API?
My concern is WEB API should be able to serve multiple requests concurrently. Since multiple instances of COM object cannot be created, planning to span a worker process per client request from WEB API. Is this right approach or is there any other best approaches to achieve this?

A process per client can be costy but it ultimately depends on the machine performance vs number of clients. Another solution is to use a single threaded TaskScheduler like in my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77780398/403671 so all calls to this COM object will be serialized. Note that if the component is properly declared in the registry (ie: ThreadingModel  value is not specified https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/inprocserver32) you shouldn't need this, COM should do all the marshaling for you (ie: loaded in Main Apartement = 1 thread).
