# Main thread errors during executing a thread unsafe program from a responsive Windows Forms app

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await, task

I would like to call a thread unsafe program asynchronously to avoid blocking the UI (Windows Forms). But my solution sometimes causes main thread problems "The automation program should be re-worked to make calls in the main thread.".

How can I solve this problem, does anyone have an idea or knows what I do wrong ?

```
private async Task<int> DoWorkAsync()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var jobFileCreated = JobFileXmlWriter.WriteXmlJobFile(mainFormData);
        // here I start the long running task
        Task <ProcessResult> result = ExecuteShellCommand(argumentXmlPaht,ProcessStartData.Arguments,mainFormData.ExportPath, 500000);
        consoleOutput = result.Result.Output;
    }
});
```

Comment: What code is causing the error? do you have an exception and stack trace? Why are you boking on `Task.Result` instead of awaiting?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21684059/17034

Comment: @PauloMorgado 
the .exe which is executed in my ExecuteShellCommand methode throws an error (sometimes), the API gives the message that the call was not made on the main thread.

Error Message: Call back not set. (null) has made an NX Open call while not on the main thread. The automation program should be re-worked to make NXOpen calls in the main thread.