# If a message queue is dequeued on an STAThread tagged method, is it good practice to ensure it is also enqueues on an STAThread tagged method?

Tags: c#, sta, concurrent-queue

Right now I am in the middle of a thorny bug having to do with message queues and, what I suspect to be, something to do with the [[STAThread]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stathreadattribute?view=net-8.0) tag or lack thereof.

My application sends messages to a communication chip in the following manner:

```
private ConcurrentQueue<Byte[]> msgQueue;

MesssageHandlerConstructor()
{ 
    try
    {
        msgQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<Byte[]>();

        BackgroundWorker messageHandlerWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        messageHandlerWorker.WorkerSupportCancellation = true;
        messageHandlerWorker.DoWork += manageMessages;
        messageHandlerWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //irrelevant catch code
    }
}

...


[STAThread]
private void manageMessages(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Byte[] message;
        
        while (!booleanToPreventCancellation)
        {
             if(!messageQueue.IsEmpty)
             {
                 msgQueue.TryDequeue(out message);

                 //some code to send a message to the chip
             }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //irrelevant catch code
    }
}
```

Messages are added to the `messageQueue` in the following manner. Note this method is inside the same `MessageHandler` class.

```
private void QueueMessage(string Name, Byte[] data)
{
    try
    {
        msgQueue.Enqueue(data)
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //irrelevant catch code
    }
}
```

My issue is that I have run into a situation where I properly enqueue a message, but the dequeuing returns the second most recent message that I enqueued, not the most recent one. This leads to my question:

If I am dequeuing messages with an [STAThread] method, must I also be enqueueing them in an [STAThread] method?

Comment: From the link which you provided: *Apply this attribute to the **entry point method** (the Main() method in C# and Visual Basic). **It has no effect on other methods.***

Comment: How many queuer and how many dequeuer threads are there? Are there any that are doing both?

Comment: also I would use just a new thread with `BlockingCollection` with foreach loop over `GetConsumingEnumerable(CancellationToken)` ...

Comment: @Charlieface the main thread is enqueueing message, there is a separate thread spawned by a background worker dequeuing them asynchronously.

Comment: Why are you using `STAThread`? You would normally only need to care about threading apartments in UI programs, or when using COM directly. Are you using COM? If you just want a simple producer-consumer pattern you should probably use a BlockingCollection as Selvin suggest.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21684059/17034